# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::colFunction()

Tags: laravel-5, controller, undefined, sql-insert

**need to insert data to database i am geting this called to undeifne method and i am totally new dont now how to define method** 
this is route line
**Route::post('/colFunction','Controller@colFunction');**
this is my controller function

```
function colFunction(Request $req)
{
 $column =$req->input('column');

 $data =array('column'=>$column);
 \DB::table('column')->colFunction($data);
}
```

Comment: what you want to do? explain proper. and error is here `->colFunction($data);` because that type of function not avalilabe in `DB query`

Comment: i want to insert data to database my table name is column and my column name is also column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

use `insert() instead of colFunction()` in your code

```
function colFunction(Request $req)
{
   $column =$req->input('column');

   $data =array('column'=>$column);
   \DB::table('column')->insert($data);
}
```

Comment: ok thats working for one function i have 4 functions like this what should i do i that case for every function

Comment: i did it for all now its saying "(2/2) QueryException
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'column' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `column` (`column`) values ())

Comment: because `column` column in table not null that's why. you always set `column` column value